# why is my organisation not available on travis-ci?

Tags: travis-ci

I setup an organisation on github a while (maybe a week) ago, and I am yet to see it appear on travis-ci.  The organisation is mr-php (https://travis-ci.org/profile/mr-php / https://github.com/mr-php).

Do I have to do something to make it appear, or if this length of wait usual?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was to do with organisation permissions.  I had to go to GitHub and into the Travis-CI app settings then give it permission to access the organisation.

Answer (score 0):

Please login into Github and then sign into Travis CI.
Give Travis permissiona to access the organisation.
And on your profile page https://travis-ci.org/profile/mr-php
use the "sync" button to synchronize your repos.
If no repos are found, file a bug.

If repos are found: flick the switch to turn Travis on for your repo.
You might also trigger your first build with a git push.
Or go back to your repo on Github and into Settings, then Webhooks & Services.
Click the "Travis CI" link, enter PW again and trigger a manual build, to test the service.